# MySql - can AFTER INSERT trigger delete the row which invoked it

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-error-1442

Let me put it in simplest words possible - **is it possible to delete the row, which actually set On the trigger** i.e. I have an `AFTER INSERT ON <table2>` trigger, the SQL in the trigger `INSERT` / `UPDATE` another `<table1>` (based on a `WHERE`), and finally tends to delete the entry/row in the  (the row which basically fired the trigger).

Trigger SQL:

```
DELIMITER ||
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_adddata_tmp ||
CREATE TRIGGER trg_adddata_tmp
AFTER INSERT ON adddata_tmp
FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM adddata WHERE data_id = new.data_id AND account_name = new.account_name) THEN
            UPDATE adddata SET data_id = new.data_id, account_name = new.account_name, user_name = new.user_name, first_name = new.first_name, last_name = new.last_name WHERE data_id = new.data_id AND account_name = new.account_name;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO adddata (data_id, account_name, user_name, first_name, last_name)
            VALUES(new.data_id, new.account_name, new.user_name, new.first_name, new.last_name);
        END IF;
        DELETE FROM adddata_tmp WHERE id = new.id;
    END;
||
```

Without the `DELETE` (just above the `END;`) the trigger works fine - `UPDATE` if exist otherwise `INSERT` - with `DELETE` statement gives the following error:

```
Error Code: 1442
Can't update table 'adddata_tmp' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

---

By the way, the error is pretty self-explanatory, but still wanted to make sure if this is possible - if not this way, may be some other way around i.e. I want the `adddata_tmp` table to be empty (or clean-ed up) all the time (on `INSERT` copies the data to main `adddata` table)

One idea, I have in mind is, to use an `EVENT` to clean-up the `adddata_tmp` based on some `status` field - which gets set as the last statement in the trigger (in place of `DELETE`).

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this with trigger, here's what the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-function-restrictions) says:

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already
>   being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the
>   function or trigger.

If `adddata_tmp` table needs to be empty all the time then I would not write trigger at all. Instead, I would recommend moving `adddata` update logic in the script/service that tries to insert the data into `adddata_tmp`.

**update**

If we are doing bulk inserts and the data (in `adddata_tmp` table) is not utilised anywhere else then we can write a cron job to clean up the table (i.e. the one that executes let's say every 10 minutes). Also, `TRUNCATE` would be more efficient (than `DELETE`) in this case.

Comment: here we're talking about 100s of records - service puts as bulk inserts (set of 100 rows).

Comment: Well, in that case, your best bet would be to write a cron job that will periodically clear `adddata_tmp` table.

Comment: Yh, I have added a new field status, and  made the trigger 'BEFORE INSERT ON' - in place of delete set the status, for which have an EVENT to clean up the table.

Comment: Do we need the status? I guess we just need to clean up the whole table, in which case, a `truncate` would be efficient.

Comment: Yh you're right, with 'BEFORE INSERT ON', we can clean it right away